# how to BOLD a fragment of the linkText in an Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
<li><%:Html.ActionLink(user.Email.Replace(Model.SearchString, "<b>" + Model.SearchString + "</b>"), "LoginEdit", "Admin", new { area = "Staff", webUserKey = user.WebUserKey }, null)%>, last login: <%:loginString%></li>
```

As you can see, I want the portion of the Email string that matches the Model.SearchString to be bolded.  I can't figure out the syntax to make this happen, given the context of my code.

Any ideas?

The goal is something like this (assuming user searched for "john"):

```
<a href="Admin/Login/Edit/456546"><b>john</b>@gmail.com</a>
```

Comment: can you show what your "final" markup needs to look like?

Comment: I have posted the final markup goal.

Comment: what is the actual markup that is being rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I encounter a situation likes this, I try my best not to embed HTML inside HTML helpers. In addition, I think breaking up your code will help in future maintenance - you're doing a lot in a single function call.

I would prefer doing it this way:

```
<li> 
    <a href="<%: Url.Action("LoginEdit", "Admin", new { area = "Staff", webUserKey =user.WebUserKey }) %>"> 
        <%: user.Email.Replace(Model.SearchString, "") %>
        <b><%: Model.SearchString %></b>
    </a>
    last login: <%: loginString %>
</li>
```

It's a few more lines of code, but it makes it much easier to decipher what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that the output of `<%: %>` is HTML encoded. So your `<b>` tag is probably encoded and you see the actual tag in the rendered HTML instead of the bold text.

If `user.Email` is a trusted value you could skip HTML encoding the output.

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink(user.Email.Replace(Model.SearchString, "<b>" + Model.SearchString + "</b>"), "LoginEdit", "Admin", new { area = "Staff", webUserKey = user.WebUserKey }, null)%>, last login: <%:loginString%></li>
```

For more information see: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx

Comment: and if it's not trusted, you can encode it in the ViewModel before passing it to the View.